# Auto language select and allowing manual lang switch

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I would like to redirect my static webpage to its translated version if the browser lang isn't my native, this isn't a hard to do, but there is a little problem with it.

What if someone is browsing the page from an internet cafe in an other country. Than the page is constantly redirecting to the lets say english version even if I click on manualy a link which supposed to link to my prefered language.

So how can I allow users to select their language if they aren't satisfied with the automaticaly selected.

I did the auto selection like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
 if(userLang != "hu" || userLang != "hu-HU"){
   window.location.replace("http://localhost/testsite/en/");
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That code looks very nice! You should prompt the user for another language by using alert(What language?)

Comment: I don't want to do that because there is a link for switch between languages so why bother the user by forcing them to choose.

Comment: You could put some ruby code in there. In ruby its very easy. all you need to write in ruby is: var = gets.chomp. This will prompt the user for there input

Answer (score 0):

**You should use some sort of storage like cookies, or localStorage.**

By default the website should send you to the translated version first, but when they switch to a page in a different language you should save it in localStorage.

**Getting the value from localstorage:**

```
var value = localStorage.{your localstorage name};
```

**Setting the value in localStorage**

```
localStorage.{your localstorage name} = {your value};
```

So say when a user decides to view the english version of a website, they click a link, javascript sets the value to english, when you arrive on the original page it will check the value, if it is english: do nothing, if it isn't set or it's something else: go to the other page.

Comment: I thought about using referrer because in theory the switch could only came from my domain and there is only two diferrent lang or three if we count the native too. I probably messed up something because if did that it always redirected even if my browser was set my native lang.